# what's the right way to write scala.Function1 as a lambda?

Tags: java, scala, lambda, java-8

I am trying to `transform()` a `Dataset` in Java as follows:

```
Function1<Dataset<Long>,Dataset<Long>> withDoubled = (Dataset<Long> numbers) -> numbers.withColumn("doubled",numbers.col("id").multiply(2));
spark.range(10).transform(withDoubled).show();
```

however, `Function1<>` gets flagged as an error saying there's multiple abstract functions to override. How do I write this as a lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of lambda's with Scala's `Function1` is not straigt forward, as lambda's work with `Interface`s having only one `abstract` un-implemented function which is not true in case of Scala's `Function1` trait.

We can use a work around for that,

First lets define builders which makes out work around reusable,

Builder for `Function1`,

```
package lambdascala;

import scala.Function1;

public class Function1WithLambdaBuilder<P1, R> {

  public static interface Function1LambdaApply<P1, R> {
    R apply(P1 p1);
  }

  private Function1LambdaApply<P1, R> lambda;

  private Function1<P1, R> function;

  public Function1WithLambdaBuilder(Function1LambdaApply<P1, R> lambda) {
    this.lambda = lambda;
    this.function = new Function1<P1, R> () {
      @Override
      public R apply(P1 p1) {
        return Function1WithLambdaBuilder.this.lambda.apply(p1);
      }
    };
  }

  public Function1<P1, R> getFunction() {
    return this.function;
  }

}
```

Another builder for `Function2`

```
package lambdascala;

import scala.Function2;

public class Function2WithLambdaBuilder<P1, P2, R> {

  public static interface Function2LambdaApply<P1, P2, R> {
    R apply(P1 p1, P2 p2);
  }

  private Function2LambdaApply<P1, P2, R> lambda;

  private Function2<P1, P2, R> function;

  public Function2WithLambdaBuilder(Function2LambdaApply<P1, P2, R> lambda) {
    this.lambda = lambda;
    this.function = new Function2<P1,P2, R> () {
      @Override
      public R apply(P1 p1, P2 p2) {
        return Function2WithLambdaBuilder.this.lambda.apply(p1, p2);
      }
    };
  }

  public Function2<P1, P2, R> getFunction() {
    return this.function;
  }

}
```

You can add builders for more `FunctionN`'s following the same pattern.

Now we can use these builders to build `Function1` and `Function2`

```
import lambdascala.Function1WithLambdaBuilder;
import lambdascala.Function2WithLambdaBuilder;
import scala.Function1;
import scala.Function2;
import java.util.List;

public class LambdaTry {

  public static void main() {

    Function1<List<Long>, List<Long>> changeNothing =
      new Function1WithLambdaBuilder<List<Long>, List<Long>>(
        // your lambda
        (List<Long> list) -> list
      ).getFunction();

    Function1<Integer, Integer> add2 =
      new Function1WithLambdaBuilder<Integer, Integer>(
        // your lambda
        (Integer i) -> i + 2
      ).getFunction();

    Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer> add =
      new Function2WithLambdaBuilder<Integer, Integer, Integer>(
        // your lambda
        (Integer i, Integer j) -> i + j
      ).getFunction();

    System.out.println(add2.apply(12));

    System.out.println(add.apply(12, 24));

  }

}
```

Comment: You can replace these convoluted builders with a single `static` factory method for each type, using the standard `Function` and `BiFunction` interfaces as input rather than defining additional interfaces.

Comment: @Holger OP wants to create instances of  `scala.Function1`, `scala.Function2`, `scala.Function3` and so on using lambda functions. As he is use these instance with some other API which expects `scala.Function1`... instances,  I do not see how `Function` or `BiFunction` can help. Can you post an answer using those.

Comment: Just replace your `Function1LambdaApply<P1, R>` with `Function<P1, R>` and your `Function2LambdaApply<P1, P2, R>` with `BiFunction<P1, P2, R>`. There is no built-in type for three-arg functions, but you didn’t post an example for three arguments either.

Comment: @Holger I provided that pattern to solve the requirement of supporting arbitrary number of Parameters only... as the OP is going to need those. I wrote this `You can add builders for more FunctionN's following the same pattern.`. Also... there are no benefits of replacing `Function1LambdaApply` by `Function`, only potential problems as you don't control the implementations of `Function` etc.

Comment: I had an issue with using a scala collections object in a filter (in java source), but encountered a similar error which this answer tipped me to as the right source of the compile error